# If $\{a_n\}$ converges to $A$, then $\{(a_1\cdots a_n)^{1/n}\}$ converges to $A$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that this sequence converges. I can't do it.

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers that converges to a number $A$. Prove that $\{(a_1\cdots a_n)^{1/n}\}$ converges to $A$.

Answer (score 8):

Since $a_n$ converges to $A$, and all numbers are positive, it follows that $\log(a_n)$ converges to $\log(A)$. By Cesaro's averaging theorem:

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \log(a_i)}{n}\rightarrow \log(A).$$

Exponentiating both sides gives the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$
x_n=\ln(a_1a_2\ldots a_n)^{1/n}=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\ln a_i.
$$
Since $\lim_na_n=A$, then $\lim_n\ln a_n=\ln A$, and therefore the sequence $(x_n)$ is convergent, with $\lim_nx_n=\ln A$. It follows that
$$
\lim_n(a_1a_2\ldots a_n)^{1/n}=\lim_ne^{x_n}=e^{\ln A}=A.
$$

Comment: why is $x_n$ convergent? The $n$-th term is $a_n/n$..  I'd say that since the terms are (defintely) bigger then $(\ln A - 1)/n$, that series diverges.. not sure though

Comment: @Ant This is a well-known result. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean

Comment: oh, I see. Didn't know about cesaro mean before.. Should check out the proof :)